# Need help recreating strange arrows in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm making a lot of automata in Tikz and I need help with one of them. I need to essentially have a copy of Figure 1 from the [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540103000907), but I have no idea how to make the edges used in **iv**, **v** and **vi** in that figure:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can make them (or something very similar) in Tikz?

Comment: You should give some lengths measured in `pt` of its width, length and circle size. 
You could make a small handmade technical drawing that gives the necessary measurements of these arrows, this would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[state, minimum width=1cm] (a) {};
\node[state, minimum width=1cm, accepting by double, right=2cm of a] (b) {};
\draw (a.north)--++(90:3mm)--([yshift=10mm]a.east)--([yshift=10mm]b.west)--([yshift=3mm]b.north)--(b.north);
\draw (a.45)--(a.north-|a.east)--(b.north-|b.west)--(b.135);
\draw[->] (a.60)--++(60:3mm)--++(0:6mm) coordinate(aux);
\draw[->] (a.70)--++(70:4mm) coordinate(aux1)--(aux1-|aux);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]